# How to monitor variable change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I receive value from server every 2 seconds. I want to run some code when the value will change. What is the best approach for this problem? Variable from server may change endlessly.
Thanks.

Comment: `if (oldValue !== newValue) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that, for whatever reason, you don't get to run code when you get the value from the server. If you do get to run code, then just compare what you get with what you have and take action if they're different

If you don't get to run code directly, you may be able to run code indirectly if you can control what the server writes to — specifically, if you can change it from `yourVar = ...` to `obj.yourVar = ...`. If so, then instead of a variable, use an object property with a getter and setter. In the setter, compare the new value to the value you already have and, if it's different, take action:

```
let value = null;
const obj = {
    get yourVar() {
        return value;
    },
    set yourVar(newValue) {
        if (value !== newValue) {
            value = newValue;
            // Take action here
        }
    }
};
```

Receive the value from the server using `obj.yourVar = ...`.

I don't recommend it, but it's possible to do this using a global variable, which would let code using `yourVar = ...` trigger your handler, by creating the accessor property on the global object (which you can access via `window` on browsers):

```js
let value;
Object.defineProperty(window, "yourVar", {
    get() {
        return value;
    },
    set(newValue) {
        if (value !== newValue) {
            value = newValue;
            console.log("New value received: " + value);
        }
    }
});

// In the code writing to it that you don't control:
yourVar = 1; // Outputs "New value received: 1"
yourVar = 1; // No output, it's not different
yourVar = 2; // Outputs "New value received: 2"
```